# Javascript - factor 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a program that I am working on but need some help. I have the user entering a minimum number and a maximum number. I have a for loop that will loop through the range of numbers and display on the screen. I also need to find the factors for each number. I have a while loop within the for loop but I am getting an "allocation size overflow" error.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function getFactors(lowNum, highNum){

var result = "Finding all factors of numbers between " 
              + lowNum + " and " + highNum + "<br /><br />"; 

for (var x=lowNum; x <= highNum; x++) {
     result +=  "<b>" + x + ":</b>";                  
    //for loop to loop through the terms


    var factor=2;
    while(factor <= lowNum){
        if (lowNum % factor == 0){      
            result += factor + ", <br />";  
        }        
        lowNum++;
    }
}
return result;

}

getFactors(2, 10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your while-loop you are incrementing `lowNum` instead of `factor`, so the loop will run forever. When changing this it works in my browser. Just watch out so users don't input too high numbers and the browser crashes/freezes.

Your logic is also a bit wrong, since you are using lowNum in your while-loop instead of x. In your code you basically don't use x.

Here is your while-loop edited so it works like intended:

```
while(factor <= x){
    if (x % factor == 0){      
        result += factor + ", <br />";  
    }        
    factor ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Izzey's answer: you are running exactly the same code for all values of `x` between `lowNum` and `highNum`. You should be working with `x` instead of `lowNum` in your `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed and edited my answer too. He is using `lowNum` instead of `x` in his while-loop